# Is it possible to have an infinite loop in pthread?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, infinite-loop

I am doing a project with pthreads and I can not go further. I have 3 threads, one thread shall read some sensor values via I2C (SMBUS), one shall calculate something by using the data porvided by the first thread, and finally last thread shall print the data on screen. A mutex shall be responsible for the synchronisation between threads. How can I use infinite `while` loop in threads, since my threads don't just "do the job and finish"? They shall continue forever (or untill Ctrl+C key is pressed).

And where should I put the `pthread_join` functions?

My first approach is below but it is not working properly:

Thanks for your help.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

typedef struct vector {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} vector_t;

typedef struct all_vectors {
    vector_t *gyro;
    vector_t *accel;
    vector_t *magnet;
} vectors_t;

vectors_t *vectors;

pthread_t th1, th2, th3;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

int main()
{
    initSensors(); //defined in another .c file

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_create(&th1, NULL, (void *) &readSensors, (void *) vectors);
    pthread_create(&th2, NULL, (void *) &calculateAngle, NULL);
    pthread_create(&th3, NULL, (void *) &printData, NULL);


    while(1)
    {
      sleep(1);
    }

    /* The program never reaches the following codes ? */ 
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void readSensors(void *vectors)
{   
    vectors_t *vecs = (vectors_t *)vectors;

    while(1)
    {   
            pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex);
            readGyro(vecs->gyro); //defined in another .c file
            readAccel(vecs->accel); //defined in another .c file
            readMagnet(vecs->magnet); //defined in another .c file
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void calculateAngle()
{
    while(1)
    {
            pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex);

            doSomeCalculation(vectors); //defined in another .c file

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void printData()
{

    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex);

        printf("%lf, %lf, %lf, lf, %lf, %lf, lf, %lf, %lf", \
               vectors->accel->x, vectors->accel->y, vectors->accel->z, \
               vectors->gyro->x, vectors->gyro->y, vectors->gyro->z, \
               vectors->magnet->x, vectors->magnet->y, vectors->magnet->z );
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        fflush(stdout); 
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: You have 4 infinite loops - what's not working?  If you intend your threads to run forever there is no point in joining them - create them as detached.  What you really seem to be missing is a way to communicate and coordinate the threads efforts.

Comment: If I dont use threads, the data is displayed correctly, but if I use threads data is not displayed correctly.

Comment: I know.  You have 4 independent actors now.  You have to coordinate them.  It is one thing to have 1 thread read, 1 thread calculate, and 1 thread print.  It is another to have them do it all in the right order to produce the expected output.  You need to look into things like queues, condition variable etc., if you want this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem surprised that code after this infinite loop

```
 while(1)
 {
   sleep(1);
 }
```

is not executed. Even if the code could reach this line

```
pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
```

you would have problems because the threads are still using the mutex. If you want a graceful shutdown of your code I would add a global boolean that you loop over while true in your threads, then add a SIGINT handler to set this to false so that the threads can exit. Then in main, remove that infinite while loop and make calls to `pthread_join` on each thread before finally destroying the mutex and finally exiting `main()`.

The `pthread_join` calls will block until the threads exit so your `main()` loop is not needed. The threads will exit gracefully on SIGINT and the program should run and terminate in a clean fashion.

One final observation: since `vectors` is a global variable you don't need to pass it to the thread via the `void*` argument since it is already visible.

Answer (score 0):

You could have infinite loops, but as you have detected that would mean that the only way to exit the program would be via an interrupt, which would not allow the program to clean up properly.

If you want it to clean up (including joining the threads etc) then you need to provide a way that the loops can exit.  One way could be a shared variable which would be set in response to some event and be in the condition for each loop so that once set all of the threads will exit.

You could set a signal handler for SIGINT to catch the ctrl-c and set the shared variable.

You call pthread_join from your main () to wait for the threads to exit.  You do not need a loop in main, it will wait until the threads you are joining are done.